# Why is it incorrect to assign arbitrary funcitons to type '(...args: unknown[]) => unknown'?

Tags: typescript

For example, why can't I assign the `sum` function to `f2`?

```js
function sum(a: number, b: number): number {
  return a + b;
}

const f1: (...args: any[]) => unknown = sum // Okay
const f2: (...args: unknown[]) => unknown = sum // Not okay
```

```
Type '(a: number, b: number) => number' is not assignable to type '(...args: unknown[]) => unknown'.
  Types of parameters 'a' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

How come the parameter types are incompatible?

Comment: A function of type, say, `(a: string) => string` is *not* a function of type `(...args: unknown[]) => string`,  because you can call the latter with any number of any type of arguments, but the former *requires* a `string` input.  See the linked q/a for more information

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/WKpppw) is a concrete example of how it's not safe to assign arbitrary functions that way